# Script for sorting lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a file that has content as below

```
hi  hello  123

cat  dog   456

     boy   456

Ind  us    90

     Can   67
```

I am trying to sort lines in this file to something like this

```
     boy   456
     Can   67
hi  hello  123

cat  dog   456

Ind  us    90
```

My code:

```
file = open("filename",'w')

column = []

for line in file:
    column.append(int(line.split()[0]))
column.sort()

file.close()
```

I didn't get desired output.

I am trying to sort elements based on first element of the row. If first element is empty that line should be printed first. Lines with first element of the row not empty should be printed later

Please help

Comment: Can you fix the file content as I have no idea what format it is supposed to be in.

Comment: Also, what about `a   b    0.0123123` in the results?

Comment: Sorry I updated the content. I am trying to sort elements based on first element of the row. If first element is empty that line should be printed first. Lines with first element of the row not empty should be printed later

Comment: Calling `split()` won't get that "empty cell". And how is that expected output sorted on the first column? `'cat' < 'hi'`

Comment: the row starting with `'hi`' is before that starting with '`cat`'? I can't see the criteria by which you're trying to sort this.

Comment: I am kind of new to python. Sorry if I asked simple question

Comment: "Simple"? No. It is unclear.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard: The criteria is,  if first element of row is empty it should be printed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File content

```
hi  hello  123
cat  dog   456
     boy   456
Ind  us    90
     Can   67
```

Basically, use the `key` of the `sorted` function to sort based upon the length of the split string.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda l: len(l.split()))
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Output

```
     boy   456
     Can   67
hi  hello  123
cat  dog   456
Ind  us    90
```